# BroadcastReceiver firing for only one action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So I am in the following situation: I want to schedule an alarm to repeat after *x* interval. This alarm should be scheduled while the user has logged into the app but not logged out.

The expected behavior would be: Schedule the alarm when the device boots up (if the user hasn't logged out). Or, schedule the alarm when the user logs in. This assures that even if the user restarts the device, the alarm will still fire.

I went about implementing this using a custom receiver which i have declared in my Manifest like so:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".notifications.AlarmBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.START_ALARMS"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This works well as the alarm is scheduled after the device boots up.

**The problem:** When I attempt to trigger this receiver like so:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent("com.example.START_ALARMS");
sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

Absolutely nothing happens!

The receiver works, that's for sure or else the alarms wouldn't fire on boot.
I am also making sure that the receiver is enabled via:

```
 ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
 PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

 pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I can't really figure out what i'm missing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the package name of your app? You can find this in the manifest it will say something like "package = blah.blah.blah".

Comment: I've checked the package and the path to the receiver. They are both ok.